# Django one form / two models

Tags: django, forms, modelform

I have a very simple model for tracking events:

```
class Event(models.Model):

    description = models.TextField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)    
    start = models.TimeField()
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    event_date = models.DateField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

and I opted to extract the location in a separate table in order to be able to perform queries:

```
class Location(models.Model):

    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30).
```

What would be the best way to create a form for inserting/updating events, taking into account that the location should be done separately and than linked via ID in the event instance? I wanted to da maybe some autocomplete field for the location address and city, but to keep it on the same form for simplicity?

Answer (score -1):

Define your own widget for the `ModelChoiceField` in the `ModelForm` that is generated for the `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well. I can insert a new location in one form, and then insert the new event in the second form, selecting manually the previuosly defined location from a dropdown menu. I was wondering how to do that in one step, maybe with two connected forms and a redirect, maintaining the PK of the selected or created location?

Comment: Once you've saved the `Location`, you can add its PK to the validated `Event` and save that model.