# Django: Cannot save related model in CBV

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have two models very similar to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6576375/1061572):

```
class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Event(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)    
    date = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I tried to save these objects in form:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = forms.CharField(label=_('City'), max_length=30)
    address = forms.CharField(label=_('Street'), max_length=30, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Event

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            self.fields['city'].initial = self.instance.location.city
            self.fields['address'].initial = self.instance.location.street
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    def save(self, commit=True):
        event = super(EventForm, self).save(commit=False)
        location = event.location
        location.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        location.address = self.cleaned_data['address']
        location.save()
        return event
```

This throws error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'city'`

I also tried to save location in CBV:

```
class EventEdit(UpdateView):
    model = Event

    def form_valid(self, form):
        event = form.save(commit=False)
        location = event.location
        location.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        location.address = self.cleaned_data['address']
        location.save()
        event.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Again, the same error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'city'`

What is the right way to save related object in class-based views?

**Update**

I have to add that I'm asking about updating existing location that is assigned to event. Adding new event location is done in `EventCreate(CreateView)` exactly as **Rohan** suggested.

```
class EventCreate(CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        location = Location()
        location.address = self.request.POST['address']
        location.city = self.request.POST['city']
        location.save()
        self.object.location = location
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `save` method `event.location` will be `None`. You need to created the `location` 
instance and then save it.

*Update*: For saving existing object:

I'm not sure your implementation of `UpdateView` is a way to go after reading [Generic views - Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms)

I would suggest the change the view as:

```
class EventEdit(UpdateView):
    model = Event

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #instance trying to update
        event = form.instance 
        location = event.location
        if location == None:
            location = Location()
        location.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        location.address = self.cleaned_data['address']
        location.save()
        event.location = location
        #event.save() instead of this do
        super(EventEdit, self).form_valid(form)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

---

Old solution:

I would change the save methods as

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    event = super(EventForm, self).save(commit=False)
    location = Location()
    location.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
    location.address = self.cleaned_data['address']
    location.save()
    event.location = location
    event.save()
    return event
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! This is exactly what I do in my `EventCreate(CreateView).form_valid()`, and it works. But I need to get and update existing location, that is already assigned to event.

Comment: Tried updated solution, now it creates new `Location` object on every update. Seems that it cannot get location (always None) from `event.location` as well as in mine version.

Comment: @VladT. Have you tried removing `save()` method from your form, I don't think that is needed.